# How to make class compatible with std::span constructor that takes a range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, std-span

I'd like to be able to pass my custom container this `std::span` constructor:

```
template< class R >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( R&& range );
```

What do I need to add to my custom class to make it satisfy the requirements to be able to pass it to the `std::span` constructor that receives a range?

For example, with `std::vector` we are able to do this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
auto span = std::span{v};
```

I've already added these to my custom class:

```
Type* begin()
{
    return m_Data;
}

Type* end()
{
    return m_Data + m_Length;
}

const Type* data() const
{
    return m_Data;
}

size_t size() const
{
    return m_Length;
}
```

...which in turn allowed me to use range-based loops, and `std::data(my_container)` as well as `std::size(my_container)`. What am I missing to make it so that I can also pass my container to the `std::span` constructor? Does it require to implement a more complex iterator?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], that includes your entire type. Also the span constructor in question lists its constraints. Did you check those?

Comment: I did look at the constraints, but I am puzzled to understand them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your `Container` does not satisfy `contiguous_range`, which is defined as:

```
template<class T>
  concept contiguous_­range =
    random_­access_­range<T> && contiguous_­iterator<iterator_t<T>> &&
    requires(T& t) {
      { ranges::data(t) } -> same_­as<add_pointer_t<range_reference_t<T>>>;
    };
```

In the `requires` clause, the return type of `ranges::data(t)` is `const Type*`, which is different from `add_pointer_t<range_reference_t<T>>` that is `Type*`.

The workaround is adding a non-`const` `data()` to your `Container` which return `Type*`:

```
Type* data()  { return m_Data; }
```

Comment: Indeed this was my issue. Does that mean std containers implement both const and non-const versions? I guess so.

Comment: @Deathicon. Not necessarily. Take `string_view` as an example, it only has one `data() const` that returns `const char*`, but since it also has only one `begin() const` and `end() const` that return `const char*`, this also makes it models `contiguous_range`.